# How to use an internal angular sdk written in typescript in a new react native mobile app

Tags: angular, typescript, react-native, cross-platform, mobile-application

I am new to react native app development, and the requirement I have is to use an existing angular sdk written in typescript and with good use of dependency injection, this sdk is an extracted piece of networking implementation of backend services with model classes, helpers etc.. that are used in angular web and angular mobile web apps and doesn't have any UI related stuff.

Now, we are rebuilding the mobile app from scratch with React Native framework, but wants to use this angular sdk within the new to be built react native app. As both angular and react native are 2 different frameworks, is there a way to achieve this?

Can anyone throw some light on this please?

Can angular headless app coexist within React Native app? I referred to this https://medium.com/appifycanada/angular-components-in-react-2c929130f995 which is interesting to see.

Please let me know if the question is not clear or need more info. Thanks